# Passing an *Awaitable* Anonymous Function as a Parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, parameter-passing

Code first. This is what I'm trying to do. I'm close, but I think I just need to fix the way I've defined my parameter in the UpdateButton method.

```
private async void UpdateButton(Action<bool> post)
{
    if (!await post())
        ErrorBox.Text = "Error posting message.";
}

private void PostToTwitter()
{
    UpdateButton(async () => await new TwitterAction().Post("Hello, world!"));
}

private void PostToFacebook()
{
    UpdateButton(async () => await new FacebookAction().Post("Hello, world!"));
}
```

Unfortunately, the `!await post()` doesn't work because, "Type 'void' is not awaitable." So the question is, how do I define my parameter in this method to support an *awaitable* parameter?

Here's how the TwitterAction().Post() is defined...

`public virtual async Task<bool> Post(string messageId){...}`

Comment: Please show your `TwitterAction.Post` method syntax, so we can show how to rework it appropriately.

Comment: An `Action<bool>` requires a boolean parameter, but you aren't supplying one.  Where does the parameter come from?

Comment: @Reed, I added the method definition for you. Thanks.

Comment: What you wanted to say is `UpdateButton(Func<bool> post)`, not `Action<bool>`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
private async void UpdateButton(Func<Task<bool>> post)
{
    if (!await post())
        ErrorBox.Text = "Error posting message.";
}
```

--EDIT--

```
UpdateButton(()=>Post("ss"));

private async void UpdateButton(Func<Task<bool>> post)
{
    if (!await post())
        this.Text = "Error posting message.";
}

public virtual async Task<bool> Post(string messageId)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => true);
}
```

Comment: Type 'System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>>' is not awaitable.

Comment: @sfjedi On the other hand, i don't get any compilation error in VS2012.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple. This does not compile. The only difference I can think of is that it's a WinRT project.

Comment: @sfjedi That's all I can think of with the info you provided.

Comment: Ahh, it was my mistake, of course. I forgot to put the `()` back in there from when I was trying @Reed's example. Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: I replaced the code that creates a new task to return a constant (true) with `Task.FromResult(true)` as it is slightly more compact/correct.  This means that the method no longer needs to be `async`, but I've left that there as it demonstrates the original intent of @jedmao's question.

Answer (score 17):

You need to pass this as a `Task<bool>`, not an `Action<bool>`.

This provides something that's "awaitable".

I believe this will work, given your current code:

```
private async Task UpdateButtonAsync(Task<bool> post)
{
    if (!await post)
        ErrorBox.Text = "Error posting message.";
}

// This will work if Post returns Task<bool> in the current API...
private void PostToTwitter()
{
    UpdateButtonAsync(new TwitterAction().Post("Hello, world!"));
}
```

---

If you do not want to start the `Task<bool>` immediately, and need to keep it as passing a lambda, there is still no reason for the lambda to be async.  In that case, you could use:

```
private async Task UpdateButtonAsync(Func<Task<bool>> post)
{
    if (!await post())
        ErrorBox.Text = "Error posting message.";
}

// This will work if Post returns Task<bool> in the current API...
private void PostToTwitter()
{
    UpdateButtonAsync(() => new TwitterAction().Post("Hello, world!"));
}
```

This causes the lambda to return the `Task<bool>` (no `async`/`await` required, as `Post` already returns `Task<bool>`), and the update method to run the lambda.

Personally, I find the first option (above) simpler, and suspect it is more likely what you want.  Given your API already returns `Task<T>`, you can just pass that around and `await` it directly.

Comment: Then I get a different error, "Method, delegate or event is expected."

Comment: @sfjedi Can you include your current declaration of the "Post" method?  How is it currently defined?

Comment: @sfjedi My current edit should work, given your last edit...  There is no need for a lambda here.

Comment: This is not the same thing. The Task is already started whereas the Action can be invoked at any time. See answer by L.B

Comment: @usr Except that, the way this works, the action is being called immediately.  There isn't any advantage *in this scenario* of adding the extra complexity, if the goal is just to check the results.  It just makes the entire thing more complex but provides no advantages of using a hot task (which is more standard)

Comment: @usr I edited to show the (complete) option which should work given a `Func<Task<bool>>` as well, but there's no real need in this case that I can see...

Comment: @ReedCopsey +1 then. I assume that the OPs code is simplified and that he needs the control flow abstraction provided by the Action. If that is not the case he should probably refactor this (just like you said).