# Type 'T' is not awaitable

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

i am creating a task scheduler so i am trying to make some kind of repeating function that accepts Task and awaits it but i get a strange Exception of `Type 'T' is not awaitable`

```
public static Task<T> Interval<T>(TimeSpan pollInterval, Func<T> action, CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        async () =>
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (token.WaitCancellationRequested(pollInterval))
                    break;

                await action();
            }
        }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

So can anyone tell me how could i await a that generic Task cuz i want the function to accept any Task, Task, bool or any other type ?

Comment: Why does `Interval` return a `Task<T>`?  It never finishes (it just goes on forever until there is an exception or it errors) and it never has a `T` value that is set as the result.

Comment: @Servy no i have a cancel token

Comment: Yes, and if it's cancelled then the task is set to a cancelled state.  It still has no *result*.  It is completed at some point, but it never has a `Result` that you can fetch.  my point is that you should return a `Task`, not a `Task<T>`, and you should accept an `Action` rather than a `Func<T>` since you discard the result of the function.

Comment: @Servy : i am so sorry but i can't get your idea; however if you understand my question. What i want to achieve is that i want the function to accept any kind of Task<string>, int or bool or every any Type... can this be achieved ? or how could i get around

Comment: Note that your function wastes a thread during the delay period.  You should use `await Task.Delay()` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845.aspx

Comment: Just accept a `Task`, and you can then accept any kind of task, but it doesn't make sense to invoke a task at all, and especially not more than once.  It seems more that you want to accept an `Action` instead.

Comment: @RuneS: You want the base (non-generic) `Task` class, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @Servy : what if Action<string> ?

Comment: @RuneS You're not passing in any string value, so that doesn't appear to make sense.  If someone has a method with parameters they'd need to curry it to create a parameterless method to pass to this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to start a long running task for this - just make your method asynchronous directly:

```
public static async Task RunAtIntervalAsync(TimeSpan pollInterval, Action action, CancellationToken token)
{
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(pollInterval, token);
        action();
    }
}
```

This will cause the `Action` to run on the current context.  If that is not required, you can use:

```
await Task.Delay(pollInterval, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
action();
```

This will cause the `Action` to not run on the same synchronization context of the caller, and potentially use a ThreadPool thread.

---

Edit in response to comments:

If you don't want the resulting task to come back canceled, but just return when the token is fired, you could use:

```
public static async Task RunAtIntervalAsync(TimeSpan pollInterval, Action action, CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(pollInterval, token);
            action();
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            // Swallow cancellation - dangerous if action() throws this, though....
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit 2:

If you want to pass in `async` lambdas, you should make the method take an `Func<Task>`, not `Action`:

```
public static async Task RunAtIntervalAsync(TimeSpan pollInterval, Func<Task> actionTask, CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(pollInterval, token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            // Swallow cancellation
            break;
        }

        await actionTask();
    }
}
```

---

Edit in response to chat:

If you want to poll, but use the results of an operation, you could use:

```
public static async Task RunAtIntervalAsync<T>(TimeSpan pollInterval, Func<Task<T>> fetchOperation, Action<T> operationOnResult, CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(pollInterval, token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            // Swallow cancellation
            break;
        }

        // Get a value
        T value = await fetchOperation();

        // Use result (ie: update UI)
        operationOnResult(value);
    }
}
```

You could then call this via:

```
RunAtIntervalAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
   async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); return "Foo"; },
   result => UpdateUI(result),
   token);
```

Comment: static class CancellationTokenExtensions
    {
        public static bool WaitCancellationRequested(this CancellationToken token, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
        }
    }

Comment: well can i just turn while(true) to while (!token.WaitCancellationRequested(pollInterval))

Comment: @RuneS That's blocking, though.  The above is completely asynchronous (non-blocking)

Comment: @RuneS: Your method, unlike Reed's code, will waste a thread during the delays. Reed's code is the correct way to write this.

Comment: @RuneS Using `await Task.Delay` allows the framework to handle this, with cancellation, in a completely asynchronous manner (without tying up a thread pool or other thread)

Comment: but while(true) will never exit

Comment: so can i replace it with while (!token.WaitCancellationRequested(pollInterval)) ? using the static class i have posted in the first comment ?.. Take a look at my first comment code

Comment: @RuneS: `Task.Delay` will throw an `OperationCancelledException` if the token is cancelled.

Comment: @RuneS: That will waste a thread, which defeats the whole point of async.

Comment: @Slaks i am so sorry for being kinda stupid but when i use while(true) beside it will never returns it just does not await

Comment: @RuneS You don't want to do that - You could use IsCancellationRequested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx instead of throwing...

Comment: @Slaks it is continuously calling the Action without any delay

Comment: @Slaks in some very strange manner when i use either while (true) or while(!IsCancellationRequested) the await inside the Action i specified is getting ignored

Comment: Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), async () =>
                                                               {
                                                                   await Task.Delay(1000);
                                                                   Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));
                                                               }, cToken.Token);

Comment: @RuneS Just edited to show another option, if you don't like doing it that way.

Comment: so the time between 2 calls must be 2 seconds the total of 1 second of default delay and the 1 awaited second

Comment: @ReedCopsey : can you look at the last couple of comments i made regarding the total await time ?

Comment: if you tried to use your code with an await inside it you will notice that it repeats regarding only the interval specified but does not awaits the await Task.Delay(x) inside the action

Comment: Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), async () =>
                                                               {
                                                                   await Task.Delay(1000);
                                                                   Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));
                                                               }, cToken.Token); || what supposed to happen here is that it awaits total of 2 seconds before repeating right ?

Comment: @RuneS See my edit 2, in that case.  In yoru case, you're passing in an async void, so it's "fire and forget", and isn't being awaited in the method.  My new edit handles that case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33932/discussion-between-reed-copsey-and-runes)

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

You can make a function that takes a generic **asynchronous** function – a function that returns a `Task<T>`.
That would be a `Func<Task<T>>`.

You can also make a function that takes a generic **synchronous** function, which is what you have now.

You can't make a single function that can take either, but you can make two overloads.

---

On an unrelated note, your function never actually uses the return value of the function.
Therefore, you shouldn't make it generic at all; you should instead take a `Func<Task>` or an `Action`.

Comment: Please can you make your answer more detailed by posting code snippets or just make it more clear cuz i can't understand you ?

Comment: @RuneS: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: What i want to do clearly is that inside this function i get an awaitable method to be repeated until i cancel it through i cancelation token... so imagine that i have a task that returns a value instead of a void.

Comment: @RuneS: An awaitable function means a function that returns a `Task`, not a `T`.  That means you want to write `Func<Task>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check an example here [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466103).
Agree with **SLaks**, you need to make the generic parameter T of Func awaitable in order to use the await.
For example if T is a `string` the code would "await" for a function that returns just a `string`.
The `await` is valid only for Tasks. For more info check this explanation [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/11/22/why-must-async-methods-return-task.aspx); the example is in VB.net.